# Finding lines in rotated image using open cv

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, opencv

I have an image which contains lot of boxes in it. My task is to find by how many degree that image is rotated. I am using `open-cv` for solving that task: first finding lines in the image, and then finding their angles and returning angles by taking mean or median as result.

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_before, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_edges = cv2.Canny(img_gray, 100, 100, apertureSize=3)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img_edges, 1, math.pi / 180.0, 100, minLineLength=1000, maxLineGap=100)

angles = []

for [[x1, y1, x2, y2]] in lines:
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(double(y2) - y1, double(x2) - x1))
```

This code I am using for finding the angle and returning the result, and for part 2:

```
(h, w) = img_before.shape[:2]
(cX, cY) = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY),angle, 1.0)
img_before = cv2.warpAffine(img_before, M, (w, h))
```

I am using this part for rotating the image by myself and checking whether I am getting the correct answer or not.

So, now, here comes the problem. My code is working correctly: I am getting an error less than `0.01` degree.
But when I am rotating an image with an integer angle - always I am getting the correct answer. But, when I am rotating it with some floating number (eg: 1.3, 1.5), I am getting worse results. Sometimes, it don't deduct a single line where for integer angle it deduct more than 2000 lines. Sometimes, I get 45 degree as resultant angle of line though I am rotating the image which is 2.5, but when I do it 2 or 3 I am getting the correct result.

Kindly help me with this. Alternatively, is there any other solution that I can use for my problem?

Comment: perhaps show such a picture. the picture must represent the problem well.

Comment: My cristal-ball says about an issue between radians and degrees.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you can assume a image of full of boxes or image like chess board with all the cube of same color.

Comment: @Ripi2 i am using degree that's why i am getting correct answer when i am rotating it with integer degree but i am getting wrong when its rotated with some floating number

Comment: What if you change that float number into radians?